# Reading in a list

Tags: c, loops, scanf, fgets, eof

I've to code a program that reads in a list of student's names and ids and sort them based on first name, last name, and id. But there are currently two problem with my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char firstName[200][21], lastName[200][51];
    unsigned short id[200]; // used short to decrease memory usage
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<200; ++i) {
    printf("Enter first name of student %d: ",i+1);
    getchar(); // FIX to consume enter
    fgets(firstName[i],21,stdin);
    printf("Enter last name of student %d: ",i+1);
    fgets(firstName[i],21,stdin);
    printf("Enter student number of student %d: ",i+1);
    scanf("%hu",&id[i]);
    printf("You've entered %s %s with ID %hu",firstName[i],lastName[i],id[i]);
    }

// other functions to do after reading in the data is successfully done
}
```

1. Reading in the values must be stopped if students reach 200 or if the user enters EOF.
2. Student's First Name or Last Name might consist of multiple parts (something like "john john" so I used fgets instead of scanf and %s to read in the word which comes after space as well but it fails and only last name is stored.

Could you tell me how to stop the loop with EOF and read in the first and last name correctly? Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the values returned by your [`getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar), [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) calls?

Comment: On an unrelated note, you should probably read and learn about *structures*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for checking the EOF , you can use function:

```
feof(FILE*) // if it returns 1 then it is EOF reached.
```

you can use it like the below snippet :

```
if (feof(fp) == 1)
break;
```

and the 2nd problem :

```
printf("Enter last name of student %d: ",i+1);
    fgets(firstName[i],21,stdin); // this is incorrect.
```

use 'lastname' instead of 'firstname'.  It should be like this :

```
fgets(lastName[i],21,stdin);
```

in this way you are overwriting the value of firstname

Comment: you can use something like : if(getchar() == EOF) break;

Comment: but where shoud i put that condition?

Comment: wherever you have used the getchar at the start

Comment: that is for consuming the enter after the third value